# Cannot shape data in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have this line of code which reads a pandas file. Then, I want to define the columns names in the same line of code but it gives me an error. I am not sure how to solve...maybe a syntax? Please advise

```
Current State: 
ratings = pd.read_csv('ratings.tsv',header=None,sep='\t', encoding= 'latin1')

Desired State: 
rating = pd.read_csv('ratings.tsv', header=None,sep='\t', encoding= 'latin1',['id','age'])
```

Comment: Use `names` parameter.

Comment: @ScottBoston Could you be please be a little more specific? I am not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try, using the `names` parameter in pd.read_csv:

```
rating = pd.read_csv('ratings.tsv', 
                     header=None,
                     sep='\t', 
                     encoding= 'latin1',
                     names = ['id', 'age'])
```